# Real-time Data Replication between Geographically Separated IBM MQ Queue Managers on AIX Power Platform

Tags: ibm-mq, aix

I am facing a data synchronization challenge involving two geographically separated IBM MQ queue managers located in different data centers. I need to achieve real-time data replication and synchronization between these queue managers on the AIX Power platform. However, the traditional approach of using multi-instance queue managers with shared file systems is not applicable in this scenario due to the physical separation of the data centers.

**Setup:** I have two IBM MQ queue managers, one in Data Center A and another in Data Center B, both running on the AIX Power platform. These centers are separated by a considerable geographic distance.

**Requirement:** My goal is to ensure real-time or near-real-time data synchronization between these queue managers, so that messages sent to one queue manager are automatically replicated and available in the other.

It's important to note that IBM MQ data and log files are typically in a proprietary format and actively managed by the messaging system. Using a general-purpose tool like rsync won't be suitable for this purpose because it's not aware of the specific format and requirements of IBM MQ data and log files.

1. What are the best practices for setting up real-time data
   synchronization between geographically separated IBM MQ queue
   managers running on the AIX Power platform?
2. Are there specific IBM MQ features or solutions optimized for this
   scenario, especially when dealing with AIX Power?
3. Are there any third-party tools or strategies that are well-suited
   for achieving real-time data replication in a geographically
   distributed environment, considering the AIX Power platform?

Comment: I would typically set this up with async replication at the storage level (ex: EMC SRDF async replication).  IBM offers on Linux only a software based replication called RDQM, if the application has a requirement too run on AIX, perhaps you can have it connect as a client to Linux based queue managers with RDQM.  FWIW I have seen rsync work for this type of situation, it doesn't need to understand the format to sync files,  it works on binary files just as well as it works on text files, however a storage based replication is a 100% better solution. You won't be able to achieve synchronous.

Comment: "Real time" doesn't mean "very fast", it means 'execution within predefined maximum times can be guaranteed'. When networking is involved, it is not possible.

Comment: Amaes, FWIW I have seen rsync work for this type of situation, it doesn't need to understand the format to sync files, it works on binary files just as well as it works on text files.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks joshMc, I decided to go with storage replication at the LUN level used by the qmgr. I found this scenario to be the most reliable also you have recommended this way in your first commend so many thanks.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question. It seems you are looking for a HA solution, but you are talking about 2 QMs, not 1 QM with multiple instances. So are you looking for a way to duplicate messages between 2 separate, simultaneously active QMs, or a way for replicating one QM to a secondary location?

Answer (score 0):

Other MQ technologies like Native HA and RDQM would be the likely choice for other platforms/deployment options.

But for AIX, I'd be looking at using IBM Storage Scale (aka GPFS) as the mechanism to do disk-level replication. You'd have to manage the failover to the DR site yourself, but the qmgr data/logs would be there to take over. Sync/async choices on the replication would determine how out-of-date the remote site is, but it would still be "reliable" and recoverable.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I appreciate the suggestion of using IBM Storage Scale (GPFS) for disk-level replication. However, I should clarify that we are already employing GPFS for data replication between the MQ cluster (two LPAR) at our Master site and the DR site. This setup is effective for ensuring high availability and disaster recovery within the data center.

but what about the two IBM MQ queue managers are located in different data centers that are physically separated, what is the best practice in this case?